# What can I use to pass the file argument in the script from the html code to cherrypy function

Tags: python, cherrypy

So what can I do to pass the argument to the function.

```
import os, random, string
import cherrypy


class StringGenerator(object):

    @cherrypy.expose        
    def index(self):        
      return """<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head 

content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>




    <!-- Bootstrap -->

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet">



  </head>

  <body>

   <div class="jumbotron">


    <p ><h4 class='text-success'  style='margin-left:30%;'>This is the twitter 
word select </h1></p>


     <form class="form-inline" action="generate/" style='margin-left:20%;' 
enctype= "multipart/form-data">




  <div class="form-group" >


    <label for="exampleInputName2">Enter the file name</label>


    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file1" id="file" placeholder=" enter the file ">


  </div><div class="form-group" >


    <label for="exampleInputName2">Enter the prefrence</label>


    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="length" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder=" enter the preference ">


  </div>


  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Result</button>


</form>



  </div> <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->


    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>


</html>"""


    @cherrypy.expose            
    def generate(self, length,file1):            
        some_string = "harsh"+length        
        cherrypy.session['mystring'] = some_string        
        fp = open(file1)      
        return fb

    @cherrypy.expose
    def display(self):    
        return cherrypy.session['mystring']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf = {
        '/': {
            'tools.sessions.on': True,
            'tools.staticdir.root': os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
        },


        '/static': {

            'tools.staticdir.on': True,
            'tools.staticdir.dir': './public'
        }
    }
    cherrypy.quickstart(StringGenerator(), '/', conf)
```

Comment: What kinda argument are you trying to pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into the file [cherrypy files tutorial](https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/blob/master/cherrypy/tutorial/tut09_files.py), but to provide you with a concrete answer, your `generate` method has to use the `file` attribute of the `file1` parameter.

For example, this method would work:

```
@cherrypy.expose            
def generate(self, length, file1):            
    some_string = "harsh" + length        
    cherrypy.session['mystring'] = some_string        
    file_content = file1.file.read()
    return file_content
```

You can also operate on the `file` attribute to get more information, it's an instance of a python [TemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile).